# Login, 2 views, 1 template - DJANGO

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a homepage and in this homepage I include my connexion.html that I connect. But I have this error : 
                 'str' object has no attribute 'visible_fields'

**my homepage HTML :**

```
{% extends "base.html" %} /* There are a css link of Bootstrap :bootstrap.min.css
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'connexion' %}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|bootstrap }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Je m'inscris" >
</form> 
...
<div class="panel-body">
    {% load bootstrap %}
    {% include "monsite/connexion.html" %}
</div>
...
```

**My connexion.html :**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
{% load bootstrap %,=
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'connexion' %}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|bootstrap }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Login" >
</form>
```

**My view of connexion :**  I have also home view

```
def connexion(request):
    error = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = connexionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pseudo = form.cleaned_data["pseudo"]
            mdp = form.cleaned_data["mdp"]
            user = authenticate(username=pseudo, password=mdp)
            if user != None :
                login(request,user)
                return redirect(reverse(accueil))
            else :
                error = True
    else :
        form = connexionForm()
    return render(request,"monsite/connexion.html",locals())
```

*connexionForm is just a forms with 2 fields in forms.py*

So I would like to login from my homepage...

Comment: Could you show us the view that renders your homepage template ? The form context variable need to ne defined in this one too, since your connexion template is just included in the home context.

Answer (score 1):

Views don't work like that.

You can't include a template and expect it to somehow call a view. A template doesn't have its own view, and templates generally don't know or care which views they're called from. Including "connexion.html" just renders it with the current template context, and in this case that doesn't have any variable named "form".

If you want to include a template with a custom context, you need to use an [inclusion template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

Comment: Ok thank you but I put the form in the home view and the verification of form is in the view connexion. The connexion view return render to homepage like the home view. I hope it's a good solution :)

Answer (score 0):

In locals(), there are form and all variables;

The error is in bootstrap|form in connexion.html but I dont know where

Comment: That is not an answer, but a comment on Cauliflower's (wrong) answer, and should be posted as a comment.